# In SQL Server 2008, how can I count rows of distinct values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table structure and data is:

```
col a     col c count
107       0
107       0
107       0 
107       0
108       0
```

What select statement can I write to get this result?
I want to count up the number of 'col a' values.

```
col a    col c count
107      4
107      4
107      4
107      4
108      1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`count() over()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) syntax:

```
select cola,
  count(cola) over(partition by cola) CountColC
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/624ed/4)

```
| COLA | COUNTC |
-----------------
|  107 |      4 |
|  107 |      4 |
|  107 |      4 |
|  107 |      4 |
|  108 |      1 |
```

If you then want to perform an update using this data you will use:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT cola, 
       colc, 
       count(cola) over(partition BY cola) CountC
    FROM yourtable
)
UPDATE cte
SET colc = countc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/624ed/12)

Comment: Need to add this to an update statement but get an error - subquery returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
select tableName.col_a, cnt
from tableName inner join
(
  select col_a, count(col_a) as cnt
  from tableName
  group by col_a
) tmp on tableName.col_a = tmp.col_a
```

for using this method in an update query:

```
update tableName set col_a = cnt
from
(
  select col_a, count(col_a) as cnt
  from tableName
  group by col_a
) tmp
where tableName.col_a = tmp.col_a
```

Comment: I actually need to do this a part of an UPDATE statement. UPDATE @hold_modified_ai_with_loc_key 
SET hmaiwlk_loc_count = ?

Answer (score 1):

If it would be okay to remove the duplicate entries, this would work:

```
SELECT cola, COUNT(1)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY cola
```

This would return:

```
    cola    colc
    107     4
    108     1
```

Comment: No I need the duplicate entries...and I need to do this as part of an UPDATE. UPDATE @hold_modified_ai_with_loc_key 
SET hmaiwlk_loc_count = ?